# Learning PHP and building a basic calculator, I get a Warning: Undefined array key when trying to retrieve values from HTML

Tags: php

This is the code in question ~ Why will num1 and num2 not get added in between the php tags.
It is a youtube tutorial so no community to ask there

```
<form action="site.php" method="get">
    
    <input type="number" name="num1">
    <br>
    <input type="number" name="num2">
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<br>

<?php     
    
echo $_GET["num1"] + $_GET["num2"] ?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

In site.php...

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

     echo $_GET["num1"] + $_GET["num2"];

}

?>


<form action="site.php" method="get">
    
    <input type="number" name="num1">
    <br>
    <input type="number" name="num2">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<br>
```

PS: In a real world scenario, echo $_GET without any sanitization will expose you to security issues, but for tutorial purposes this answer should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you! ~ does it make a difference if the php block is above  or below the HTML?

Comment: In this case I prefer it because when teh answer is given, then you will see the form again (and you'll be able to make another calculation. Enjoy your PHP journey :)